# Reduce space between columns when using \usepackage{multicol} & \SetEnumitemKey

Tags: horizontal-alignment, multicol, format-files

The MWE code below executes perfectly. But I need to reduce by 50% the horizontal space between the 2 cols.

Have tried pasting this string at different places in the preamble and after \begin{document}

Nothing works. Your help is sincerely appreciated. **If possible, please explain why** `\setlength\columnsep{10pt}` not working.

Also (and this is being  really OCD), is it possible to **correct the horizontal alignment between the 2 cols**? I suspect the use of both fractions and non-fraction answer choices in the same line is messing up the alignment.

[screenshot of horizontal misalignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gs5oq.jpg)

MWE

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newlist{options}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[options]{label*=(\Alph*)}
\newcommand{\option}{\item}

\SetEnumitemKey{twocol}{
  before=\raggedcolumns\begin{multicols}{2},
  after=\end{multicols}}

\begin{document}

 %This code creates the text before the first question
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{center}
 \fbox{\fbox{\parbox{5.5in}{\centering
    Pre-Algebra Covid: Week 4 Item 2}}}
\end{center}

\vspace{5mm}

%Here, the questions begin
\begin{questions}

 % Q 1
 \question $\displaystyle\frac{4x^4y^3}{2x^3}$
 \bigskip

 \begin{options}[twocol]
  \option $2xy^3$\\
  \option $\displaystyle\frac{4x^2y^3}{2}$\\
  \option $\displaystyle\frac{24x^7}{y^2}$\\
  \option $\displaystyle\frac{4x}{9y^2}$\\
 \end{options}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It NEVER occurred to me to use **negative** units to adjust the column separation. That's what social distancing will do a man's mind.

Inserting this line of code (see below) did the trick!
`setlength{\columnsep}{-10cm}` after...\usepackage{multicol}

I still welcome your help solving the **vertical column misalignment** shown in the img link above.
Hope this helps some other Covid-closed school teacher! :)

h/t ghostanime2001 @ latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=15664

Comment: Please make sure that all images are uploaded using the official Stack Exchange interface, i.e. the image icon on top of the text field (shortcut: Ctrl+G). This ensures that all images will always be accessible and won't expire.

Comment: Maybe an easier alternative: https://ctan.org/pkg/tasks

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really sure what you are trying.

Given the design you made you have

```
text in full width .............
................................

a multicol        at half of
splitting the     the \linewidth
```

So your 4 answers come exactly where they should and a bigger \columnsep would not change that, it only makes the columns smaller but not alter their starting point. Using a negative \columnsep is different but it effectively means your second column overwrites the first. (works in your case as you columns are basically empty, but wouldn't if (A) or (B) has more material).

So I'm not sure why you don't simply use `{multicols}{4}` and have all answers on a single line given that they are so short.

But if you are really determined to have 2 columns and a lot of white spaces on the right try something like this:

```
\SetEnumitemKey{twocol}{
  before=\setlength\linewidth{.5\linewidth}%
         \raggedcolumns\begin{multicols}{2},
  after=\end{multicols}}
```

This way multicols sees a text line widths of only half of what it really is and accordingly the two columns it forms are absed on that width.

As to the vertical "mis"alignment ...: multicol  doesn't align individual lines in different columns it just breaks the galley into columns and if (A) is normalsized by (C) is extra high, then they do not line up.
If you want everything line up, you better use a table or an array but if you want auto breaking via multicol then either you have to accept this or manually make things the same height, e.g.,

```
  \option $2xy^3 \phantom{\displaystyle\frac{4x}{9y^2}}$\\
```

which is not that pretty (but could be done nicer).

Anyway, with the above changes you get

[image]

The first line in the example was generated using

```
\SetEnumitemKey{fourcol}{
  before=\raggedcolumns\begin{multicols}{4},
  after=\end{multicols}}
```

To reduce the width even there, one can apply the same trick, eg

```
\SetEnumitemKey{fourcol}{
  before=\setlength\linewidth{.6\linewidth}%   % -- 60 percent of the normal width
  \raggedcolumns\begin{multicols}{4},
  after=\end{multicols}}
```

or some other value, or one could generally redue the width of the galley by specifing

```
\setlength\textwidth{4in}  % or some other value
```

in the document preamble.

Comment: I'm honored that someone of your predigree in latex development choose to answer my post! This situation is a real mess. I teach low level maths in a Covid-closed high school. Quizzes must post to Canvas LMS. I have to copy/paste images of ea. prob into Canvas. But many students view assignments on cell phones bcs they lack computers at home. Being a major LaTeX newby, I was ineptly trying to render a cell phone screen friendly image that minimized the spread of the answer choices. Your solution is most elegant! On the 1 line example, possible to decrease choices spacing? tks

Comment: @WyoWindStorm no need to feel honored, just support LaTeX development if it helps you, e.g., https://github.com/sponsors/FrankMittelbach :-).  As to your question: yes situation right now is difficult for all of us. If you generally want suitable phone sizes, why not try \setlength\textwidth{4in} or some other value in the preamble, with or without my other solution. This way everything you write will be bound by a smaller overall width. Hope that helps - Frank